Change the style of answer numbers on the question page to make positive-scored answers stand out
Currently, on pages that show a list of questions, the number of answers is displayed in one of three styles:

Gray font without a surrounding box, if it has 0 answers;
Green font in a box with green border, if it has at least one answer but no accepted answers;
White font in a box filled with green, if it has an accepted answer.

The styles are illustrated in the following screenshots:
 for no answers;
 for answers not accepted;
 for accepted answer.
I would like to propose a new style for questions that have been answered, but none of the answers has a net positive score. If I understand correctly, this is similar to the criteria for a question to appear in the "unanswered" tab. A possible choice is using gray font in a box with gray border like this:

Another choice is simply use the first style (0 answers) listed above for this case:

If this change is applied, the second style shown in the above list would be changed to apply only to questions with positive-scored answers. I believe the change can assist users to quickly locate questions that are more worthy of answering, serving a similar purpose of the "unanswered" tab while providing a more straightforward user experience.
The actual criteria for the new style (especially for the case where there are negative-scored accepted answers) and the actual style used are open for discussion. In particular, the style can be fine-tuned to make things less confusing for new users.
I have found a very old feature request along a similar line of idea, but that feature request has not been implemented and I believe things have changed a lot in the past years. Also while related what is proposed in that question is not exactly the same as what is proposed here, as it did not take into account the existence and the criteria of the "unanswered" tab (which may not have existed back then).

I like it. We now recognize that votes are a better indicator than acceptance, but this UI element is still boldly highlighting acceptance while ignoring votes. Some tweak like this would make sense.

There are two stack exchange search filters that can already be applied that gives us a list of questions as follows: isanswered:yes giving the search options: questions only not deleted is answered, which gives us a list of questions with a least one positive scored answer, and: isanswered:no answers:1.. giving the search options: questions only not deleted not answered answers>= 1, which gives us a list of questions with answers but no positive scored answers. A problem with this seems to be that there is no way to apply search filters to all searches, for example.

@PeterJames I am aware of the search filters, but this is a suggestion that changes the default style for users (even for those who have not logged in) without any additional actions from them. I have merged your suggestion to the question.

@WeijunZhou I thought you might be aware of those particular filters, but I think it's relevant to mention the possibility of using filters to achieve this, especially because you mention "the change can assist users to quickly locate questions that are more worthy of answering". If somebody is really looking for these questions then they would know about the filters or (even SEDE ). I think your suggestion might be useful for people to avoid looking at questions which have no useful answers.

I am neutral in adding those additional info to the question. You can directly edit the question to include them if you want.

The idea is fine but I don't like the mock-up. Borders for me don't have meaning; they just group related parts of the UI.

@Laurel You can present your ideal mock up as an answer.
